# Client {CLIENT_ID} not found or disabled', 'error_detail_key': 'E20109', 'error_uri': 'https://dev.xing.com/docs/error_responses'}

Tags: api, xing

I am trying to create a monitoring service for Xing. When I try to get de access token with the following request:

```
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(app_key, app_secret)
    client = oauth2.Client(consumer)

    ...       

    params = {
        "client_id": app_key,
        "client_secret": app_secret,
        "redirect_uri": app_callback_url,
        "code": code,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    }  
    _, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST", body=urllib.parse.urlencode(params))
```

I get the following response:

{'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Client {CLIENT_ID} not found or disabled', 'error_detail_key': 'E20109', 'error_uri': 'https://dev.xing.com/docs/error_responses'}

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the "client_secret" from the parameters and adding the "code_verifier"